# How to record video and audio with ffmpeg and pipe only audio to python process

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have an ffmpeg command recording video and audio as one output and
I'm trying to add a second output to pipe out only the raw audio to python so that I can run additional processing on the audio chunks.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

record_audio_video_command = f"ffmpeg -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 \ 
                             -vcodec libx264 output.mp4 -f s16le pipe:1"

record_command = Popen(record_audio_video_command, 
                        shell=True, 
                        stdout=PIPE, 
                        stderr=STDOUT)

f = open("output.txt", "w")
data = record_command.stdout.read(320)
f.write(str(data))
while len(data) > 0:
    data = record_command.stdout.read(320)
    f.write(str(data))
```

Is there a way to have ffmpeg pipe out only the raw audio bytes as one output, while still recording video and audio as the other output?

Comment: It is possible, but it's too difficult to answer your question in its current form. **1.** The FFmpeg command line reads audio and video from audio and video devices that we don't have (that makes in unreproducible). Since audio/video source is not relevant to the question, please use a sample file as input. For example, use [small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEvbcsLqrj4AN-gOiV1PezMmMvuQqzyh/view?usp=sharing). **2.** `m3u8` output format is complicated and not relevant, please use other format as MP4. **3.** Post an example that uses two outputs

Comment: **4.** Using `pyaudio` doesn't seem relevant (makes things more complicated). **5.** Try to post a reproducible (and executable) code sample that includes the relevant import statements and that we can actually execute. I expect to see two code samples: one that records the video, and one that reads the audio from FFmpeg subprocess `stdout` pipe and stores the output of the pipe to an output file (saving the output from the pipe to a file is important for making the code reproducible).

Comment: I updated the question with an example. The output file with the stdout data seems to have more than just the raw audio bytes.

Comment: Can you please respond my answer?

Answer (score 0):

We may split the solution into stages that are easier to test:

First we better try using FFmpeg CLI for encoding two MP4 files, one with video and audio stream, and one with audio only.
The input file `small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4` has 6 audio channels, we may convert the audio to stereo as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1410620/635712):

`ffmpeg -y -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0=c2+0.30*c0+0.30*c4|c1=c2+0.30*c1+0.30*c5" -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4 -vn -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -acodec aac output2.mp4`

Note that I didn't notice that `small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4` has 6 audio channel when I recommended to use it as input.

We can verify that `output.mp4` and `output2.mp4` are valid MP4 files.

---

Second test: pass raw audio with `s16le` format to the second file:
`ffmpeg -y -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0=c2+0.30*c0+0.30*c4|c1=c2+0.30*c1+0.30*c5" -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4 -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -f s16le output2.s16le`

Convert `output2.s16le` to MP4 with AAC codec for testing:

`ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -i output2.s16le -acodec aac output3.mp4`

Verify that `output3.mp4` is valid MP4 files (with valid audio stream).

---

Third test: replacing the second file with a PIPE (write the output of `stdout` to `output3.s16le`):

`ffmpeg -y -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0=c2+0.30*c0+0.30*c4|c1=c2+0.30*c1+0.30*c5" -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4 -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -f s16le pipe:1 > output3.s16le`

Verify that `output2.s16le` and `output3.s16le` have the same content.

---

Python implementation:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import shlex

# In case we are using Linux, we have to use shlex.split (in Windows we don't).
record_audio_video_command = shlex.split('ffmpeg -y -i small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4 -af "pan=stereo|c0=c2+0.30*c0+0.30*c4|c1=c2+0.30*c1+0.30*c5" \
                                          -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac output.mp4 -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
                                          -channel_layout stereo -f s16le pipe:1')

record_command = Popen(record_audio_video_command, stdout=PIPE)

with open("output4.s16le", "wb") as f:  # Open file as binary file
    data = record_command.stdout.read(320)
    f.write(data)
    while len(data) > 0:
        data = record_command.stdout.read(320)
        f.write(data)
```

---

Verify that `output4.s16le` and `output3.s16le` have the same content.

---

Notes:

- We have to open the output file as binary file - use `"wb"` argument.
  Write binary data to the file - don't convert the data to string.
- We may either use `with open(...) as f` in a nested code block or use `f.close()` for closing the file.
- It is recommended not to use `shell=True` (it considered to be unsafe).
- Use `shlex.split` for splitting the command into a list of command and arguments (in Windows it may work without splitting).