# How can I smoothly stream frames from a video that is currently being recorded (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to stream a video (into numpy arrays) while recording it in Python.  Currently, I am recording using ffmpeg, and opencv to read it, but it is not going smoothly.

**GOAL: Receive and record a video stream in real-time, into a video file with reasonable compression, while being able to have fast random access to any frame received up to that point (minus perhaps an acceptable buffer of e.g. 30 frames / 1 second).**

**The frame read from a given index lookup must always be identical.. i.e. if we open the video later and read from it again, we must get identical frames as when we read them "live".**

Here is my current code (which runs on Mac), which attempts to save a video stream from the camera, while reading from the video file as it is being written to.

```
import datetime, os, subprocess, time, cv2

video_path = os.path.expanduser(f"~/Downloads/stream_{datetime.datetime.now()}.mkv")
# Start a process that record the video with ffmpeg
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'avfoundation', '-framerate', '30', '-i', '0:none', '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', video_path])
time.sleep(4)  # Let it start
assert os.path.exists(video_path), "Video file not created"

# Let's simulate a process that gets random frames from the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
try:
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # print(f"Captured frame of shape {frame.shape}" if frame is not None else "No frame available")
        if frame is not None:
            print(f"Got frame of shape {frame.shape}")
            cv2.imshow("Q to Quit", frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print(f"No frame available on {video_path}.. waiting for more frames...")
            time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

process.terminate()
cap.release()
```

This code never loads a frame.

Things I have discovered:

- If I renew the cap with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)` in the else block, it does start showing frames from the start of the recording.  After using up all frames, it stops.  If I keep track frames seen so far and do

```
        else:
            print(f"No frame available on {video_path}")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
            print(f"Restarting video capture from frame {frames_seen_so_far}")
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frames_seen_so_far)  # DOES NOT WORK
```

It does not work (the `cap.set..` makes no difference).

Comment: wait... did you expect to be writing into a file with ffmpeg AND READ from that file AT THE SAME TIME? I could say technically it's not impossible, but you need a different answer: "no".  that approach is wrong. scrap all that and instead just describe the goal. then describe the goal of the goal. don't be chained to your chosen approach. -- opencv is also the wrong library for this. use ffmpeg or gstreamer.

Comment: Yes - that is what I expected.  I restated the goal above and put it in bold.  I'll put the goal of the goal here: "GOAL OF GOAL: Run live object detector on video stream, while recording stream such that results are exactly reproducible when run on recorded video, and any past frame can be observed on request".  "GOAL OF GOAL OF GOAL: Improve search and rescue with live object detection from drones".

Comment: yeah... you can't send that to a file and then read from the same file while it's still being written. that also costs you pointless decoding. you need _one_ process that reads from the camera, tees that (uncompressed, in-process) feed off to the vision stuff and to the compression and storage. and you need to handle the vision processing being slower than the video feed, so it needs to be able to drop frames. if you throttle them, they queue up and your RAM explodes and the whole thing catches fire.

Comment: If I understand you correctly Christoph, the problem with what you propose is that results will be unreproducible.  The vision stuff will run on the uncompressed (or at least un-recompressed) video from the capture, but then the video will be saved with compression. So the results from the vision system will be unreproducible.  The slower-vision is no problem - I can just record which frames were skipped.

Comment: so now you want random access too! that'll require some engineering. the media container must not require finalizing, so MP4 is out of the question. you'll need an mpeg transport stream. and since you'll write those frames yourself (with ffmpeg), you actually _set_ the timestamp for each frame, so you'll get exactly that. -- since you need pixel-perfect reproduction, you'll either have to store losslessly, or encode and then decode (both in ram, NOT reading from the file) and then process. you didn't say you cared about compression degrading the image, only that you require recall to be exact

Comment: an mkv container is also *not* likely to be readable while it's not finalized. you might as well store individual frames then. just store JPEGs.

Comment: For those reading this far down the thread.  I solved the problem (well kind of) by creating a [LiveVideoReDecorder](https://github.com/petered/eagle_eyes_video_scanner/blob/734e37b497ec1adcbb2fc51223e160b468e3bdd1/video_scanner/general_utils/video_livestream_recorder.py) class that lets you read with random access while writing.  Internally it writes video in chunks while keeping an in-memory buffer of the current chunk so you can always read up to the last frame written.  Only downside is that since it writes as mp4, there is compression and frames will not be identical when re-read.

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg CLI supports multiple outputs in one command.
We may set the first output as recorded video file, and the second output as `pipe:`.
That way we can recorded the video, and get the raw video frames from `stdout` pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.

My [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76443636/4926757) shows something similar, while grabbing the audio.
We may use the same concept from grabbing the video while recording.

For having fast random access to recorded video frames, we may use [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for splitting the recorded input to multiple 1 second duration files.

---

Before grabbing a live video, we better test the solution by grabbing video from the following MP4 [input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEvbcsLqrj4AN-gOiV1PezMmMvuQqzyh/view).

Code sample:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np

video_path = 'recorded_video.mkv'  # Output video file name

input_file_name = 'small_bunny_1080p_60fps.mp4'

# We may skip the following part, if we know the resolution from advanced
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_file_name)  # Open video stream for capturing (just for getting the video resolution)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
cap.release()

# Start a process that record the video with ffmpeg and also pass raw video frames to stdout
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-an', '-i', input_file_name, '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', video_path,
                            '-f', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', 'pipe:'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


while True:
    raw_frame = process.stdout.read(width*height*3)  # Read raw video frame as bytes array

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):        
        break  # Break the loop in case of too few bytes were read - assume end of file (or turning off the camera).

    # Transform the bytes read into a NumPy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
    frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 3))
    cv2.imshow("Q to Quit", frame)  # Show frame for testing
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
  
process.stdout.close()  # Close stdout pipe
process.wait(1)  # Wait 1 second before terminating the sub-process.
process.terminate()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Grabbing from a video camera:
When grabbing from a video camera, we add "-rtbufsize 100M" argument for reducing the chance for losing frames (larger "real-time buffer" allows FFmpeg to store buffered frames instead of dropping them).

In the following example I am using my webcam for testing (also using `-f dshow` instead of `-f avfoundation`, since I am using Windows 10):

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np

video_path = 'recorded_video.mkv'  # Output video file name

# We may skip the following part, if we know the resolution from advanced
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Open video stream for capturing (just for getting the video resolution)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
cap.release()

#process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'avfoundation', '-framerate', '30', '-i', '0:none', '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', video_path])

# Start a process that record the video with ffmpeg and also pass raw video frames to stdout
# Example for reading from a webcam, use "-rtbufsize 100M" for reducing the chance for losing frames.
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-an', '-f', 'dshow', '-rtbufsize', '100M', '-framerate', '30', '-i', 'video=Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000', 
                            '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', video_path,
                            '-f', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', 'pipe:'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


while True:
    raw_frame = process.stdout.read(width*height*3)  # Read raw video frame as bytes array

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):        
        break  # Break the loop in case of too few bytes were read - assume end of file (or turning off the camera).

    # Transform the bytes read into a NumPy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
    frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 3))
    cv2.imshow("Q to Quit", frame)  # Show frame for testing
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
  
process.stdout.close()  # Close stdout pipe
process.wait(1)  # Wait 1 second before terminating the sub-process.
process.terminate()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**Having fast random access to recorded video frames:**

Since we can't capture frames from the a video file that is not closed, we may use [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) for splitting the recorded input to multiple 1 second duration files (using FLV container instead of MKV).
In that way, we have access (and seeking capability) to the recorded video frames.

Code sample using segment demuxer:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np

# We may skip the following part, if we know the resolution from advanced
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Open video stream for capturing (just for getting the video resolution)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
cap.release()

#process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'avfoundation', '-framerate', '30', '-i', '0:none', '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', video_path])

# Start a process that record the video with ffmpeg and also pass raw video frames to stdout
# Example for reading from a webcam, use "-rtbufsize 100M" for reducing the chance for losing frames.
# Set segment time to 1 second.
# The output files are going to be 00000000.flv, 00000001.flv, 00000002.flv, 00000003.flv... (each file is 1 second).
# Use "-g 30`" encoding argument for adding as key frames every 30 frames (and "-flags +cgop" for assuring close GOP).
process = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-an', '-f', 'dshow', '-rtbufsize', '100M', '-framerate', '30', '-i', 'video=Microsoft® LifeCam HD-3000', 
                            '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-flags', '+cgop', '-preset', 'fast', '-crf', '23', '-b:v', '8000k', '-g', '30',
                            '-f', 'segment', '-segment_time', '1', '-reset_timestamps', '0', 
                            '-segment_list', 'list.txt', '-segment_list_type', 'ffconcat', '%08d.flv',
                            '-f', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', 'pipe:'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


while True:
    raw_frame = process.stdout.read(width*height*3)  # Read raw video frame as bytes array

    if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):        
        break  # Break the loop in case of too few bytes were read - assume end of file (or turning off the camera).

    # Transform the bytes read into a NumPy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
    frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 3))
    cv2.imshow("Q to Quit", frame)  # Show frame for testing
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
  
process.stdout.close()  # Close stdout pipe
process.wait(1)  # Wait 1 second before terminating the sub-process.
process.terminate()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

After finish recording, we may merge the segment into a single video file using FFmpeg concat demuxer:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy recorded_video.mkv`

---

We may ensure that seeking is working:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('00000003.flv')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 10)
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey()  
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

---

Notes:

- Ensuring that the recorded video is synchronized with the live video is challenging.
  Thorough testing and parameters tuning is required.
- The benefit of grabbing and recording using one FFmpeg command is not so large.
  For enduring frames synchronization, we may consider grabbing the frames (say suing `cv2.VideoCapture`), and record the grabbed frames using FFmpeg sub-process.
  That way, even when captured frames are "lost", the frame synchronization is ensured.
  We may also open a new video file every second instead of using segment demuxer.

Comment: Quality-answer.  If I'm getting it correctly, there still will be the problem of unreproducability (as in the numpy frames from the livestream will not exactly equal those from re-reading the recorded video due to compression artefacts).  But that is fine.  I also have the issue of the live video (but not the recorded) showing 6 copies of me in a 2x3 grid brady-bunch style - but that may be related to me using avfoundation format on mac, instead of dshow....

Comment: Brady-bunch problem solved with flags '-video_size', f'{width}x{height}'

Comment: Ah... I take it from your last comment that it's hard to know which frame in the livestream corresponds to which frame in the recorded video... That would be a problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to know since each file has 30 frames. It may be hard to verify.

Comment: What I mean is there's not really a way to verify which frame in the record video(s) the frame retrieved in the i'th iteration of that `while True` loop corresponds to (since it may repeat or skip frames), assuming I understand correctly.

Comment: When the system / CPU is loaded, there is a chance for skipping frames. There are all kind of design considerations that we have to address when dealing with video in real-time. We may have to configure the priorities of the threads/processes for example. We may use hardware accelerated encoding for reducing CPU load... Using FFmpeg as a subprocess in Python may not be the most robust architecture, compared to using the C interface of FFmpeg for example. It doesn't mean that the above solution is not going to work. The software design considerations exceeds the scope of the question...

Comment: Also if I understand correctly, if the CPU is not loaded, there's a chance of repeating frames.  Unfortunately this kills it for my application - due to the hard requirement that the frame lookup for a given index must be identical when read "live" vs "in replay".  Differences due to compression artefacts I can live with but differences in actual frame index are a problem in my case.  I ended up building a solution involving cv2.VideoWriter and your idea of 1 second segments - I'll post here once complete.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: In my experience repeating frames are side effect of missing frames, or result of bad configuration. Are you having repeated frames?